# Eliminating terms of a Hypergeometric differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

I have a Schrödinger-like wave equation,

$$
\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} +\left[ \omega^2 + Q_0 + \frac{Q'''}{3!}(x-x_0)^3\right]\psi = 0
$$
from which we note there is one pole in $x \to \infty$. Following this [article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html), we can convert any ODE with less than three ordinary singular points into a hypergeometric equation,
$$
z(z-1)F''+[(a+b+1)z-c]F'+ abF = 0 \,\, .
$$

To perform this conversion, I think it's necessary to eliminate the term proportional to $F'$. So my question are:

1. Is it really possible to convert the wave equation into the Hypergeometric one? Why?
2. What's the mechanism to perform this conversion (change of variables, new parametrization)?

Comment: Why is $x_{0}$ a pole? There are no divergent coefficients here.

Comment: Hey @GattuMytraya, I was wrong. The question was fixed.

Comment: @Gonçalo, Yes, they are!